# Do not automatically pend some additions in TFS plug-in for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I am using TFS plugin for eclipse, i want to make my `\bin` (It's an Android Project) folder's changes not reflected in TFS, we can say it as "unbinding" or "making it offline". Is that possible by Eclipse TFS plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology used by most source control providers, including TFS, is *ignored*.

The TFS plug-in for Eclipse will honor Eclipse's "derived resource" settings, which is resources that are built from the rest of the project resources.  That is to say that your `bin` directories should be ignored by your Eclipse settings.  You may wish to double-check your project configuration to ensure that your filesystem layout reflects what Eclipse believes to be your project layout.  (This can happen, for example, if you have a maven-style project configuration and use maven exclusively to produce builds, but you do not use `mvn` to setup your Eclipse projects and workspace.)

However, you can also accomplish this manually, as the TFS plug-in for Eclipse has an *ignore file* like most other source control providers.

From within the Eclipse package explorer, you can simply right click on your `bin` folder and select Team > Ignore.  This will create the appropriate ignore file and add an entry for your entire `bin` folder (recursively).

You can also update the file manually, in TFS 2010 and prior, this file is the [`.tpignore` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413275%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  In TFS 2012, with local workspaces, Visual Studio and the TFS plug-in for Eclipse have standardized on the new [`.tfignore` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/jj155786.aspx).