# Disable automatic adding of files with TFS Everywhere plug-in in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin, team-explorer-everywhere

Is it possible to disable the automatic adding of new files to TFS in Eclipse without using the .tpignore configuration file? I would like to distinguish which file of a folder is added to TFS. For example the TFS plug-in tries to add the temporary file created when a version controlled excel sheet is opened. For me this is currently the biggest issue with the TFS Everywhere plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective and convenient way is using  the `.tpignore` file which  in TFS 2010 and prior. In TFS 2012, with local workspaces, Visual Studio and the TFS plug-in for Eclipse have standardized on the new `.tfignore` file.

Possible duplicate with [Do not automatically pend some additions in TFS plug-in for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052310/do-not-automatically-pend-some-additions-in-tfs-plug-in-for-eclipse) .

> The terminology used by most source control providers, including TFS,
>   is ignored.

You could also add the file format in the [list defined files which are ignored in TFS by default.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224302/what-files-are-ignored-in-tfs-by-default/43227500#43227500)

---

To  distinguish which file of a folder is added to TFS  you could use some third-party tool such as **TFS power tools**, the file in TFS will have  a green small arrow in the lower left corner of the file, just as the screenshot in my reply of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522892/how-to-check-in-to-tfs-when-all-files-have-been-replaced-removed).